# Samba: authenticate against Active Directory using winbind but authorize against separate OpenLDAP server

Tags: centos, centos7, samba, samba4, winbind

#### Short Version

How can I configure a CentOS 7 machine with Samba 4.8.0 serving users on Windows 7 clients to *authenticate* using their domain login credentials (`winbindd` and Active Directory) but be *authorized* (i.e. perform user/group lookup) against a separate OpenLDAP server?

This was [easy](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba,_Active_Directory_%26_LDAP) with CentOS 6 and the Samba fallback mechanism. It seems to be more complicated once winbind must be involved.

#### Long Version

We have a CentOS 7 machine that needs to share files with Windows 7 machines in an Active Directory domain (that I do not control) for users in the EXAMPLE.COM domain but perform user/group lookup against a separate OpenLDAP server (that I do control) at ldap.mydomain.com. With current versions of CentOS 7, as of Samba 4.8.0, [the winbindd fallback is no longer available and winbindd is required](https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.8.0.html).

So we do the following:

- open firewall port 445 (but for testing, `systemctl stop firewalld`)
- set SELinux Booleans for sharing home directories (but for testing, `setenforce 0`)
- add trust for the certificate authority that certified ldap.mydomain.com (tested and LDAP lookups are functional on the system)
- install packages `samba`, `samba-client`, `samba-winbind`, `samba-winbind-clients`, and `samba-winbind-krb5-locator`
- `net ads join -U 'user'` (the domain allows non-admin creation of machine accounts; `net ads testjoin` returns 'Join is OK')
- `authconfig --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --disablemkhomedir --update`

Here is the `smb.conf` with provisions for winbind, which was not configured by `authconfig` above:

```
[global]
    strict locking = no
    workgroup = EXAMPLE
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    disable netbios = yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    security = ads
    realm = EXAMPLE.COM
    ldap ssl = off
    idmap config * : backend = ldap
    idmap config * : ldap_url = ldaps://ldap.mydomain.com:636/
    idmap config * : ldap_base_dn = dc=mydomain,dc=com
    idmap config * : ldap_user_dn = uid=samba,ou=agents,dc=mydomain,dc=com
    idmap config * : read only = yes
    idmap config * : range = 1000-65535
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab
    load printers = no
    printcap name = /dev/null
    printing = bsd
    disable spoolss = yes
[home]
    comment = Home Directories
    path = /home/%U
    browseable = no
    writable = yes
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0700
    valid users = EXAMPLE\%U
    preexec = ls /home/%U
[share]
    path = /home/share
    writable = yes
    valid users = @share
    force group = share
    create mask = 0660
    directory mask = 0770
    preexec = ls /home/share
```

Here is the problem:

- `smbclient //myhost.fqdn/home -U <user>` performs winbind authentication and successfully connects to the share for any value of `<user>`
- `smbclient //myhost.fqdn/share -U <user` performs winbind authentication but fails to determine from ldap.mydomain.com that `<user>` is in group 'share', thus returning `tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`

Additional information:

- `testparm` shows no errors or warnings
- `wbinfo -u` returns list of EXAMPLE.COM domain users
- `wbinfo -g` returns list of EXAMPLE.COM domain groups
- SSH login of domain users (i.e. ssh user@host) works
- `log.winbindd-idmap` shows:

```
[2019/06/08 15:58:23.175342,  3] ../source3/winbindd/idmap.c:397(idmap_init_domain)
  idmap backend ldap not found
[2019/06/08 15:58:23.177972,  3] ../lib/util/modules.c:167(load_module_absolute_path)
  load_module_absolute_path: Module '/usr/lib64/samba/idmap/ldap.so' loaded
[2019/06/08 15:58:23.179407,  2] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:847(smbldap_open_connection)
  smbldap_open_connection: connection opened
[2019/06/08 15:58:23.340963,  3] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1069(smbldap_connect_system)
  ldap_connect_system: successful connection to the LDAP server
[2019/06/08 15:58:23.343603,  1] ../source3/winbindd/idmap_ldap.c:484(idmap_ldap_db_init)
  idmap_ldap_db_init: failed to verify ID pool (NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)
[2019/06/08 15:58:23.343810,  1] ../source3/winbindd/idmap.c:447(idmap_init_domain)
  idmap initialization returned NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

Setting a higher debug level suggests that the final NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL comes from an attempt to make changes to the basedn, but I do not understand why `idmap backend ldap not found` appears or why Samba/winbind needs to make changes to the LDAP database, particularly when the readonly property is set in `smb.conf`. Finally, I am not sure if these lines even explain the problem.

We have a working CentOS 6 deployment that perfectly functions without winbind while performing this split Active Directory authentication with separate LDAP user/group lookup. How can we achieve what we want with Samba 4.8.0 in CentOS 7? Why are the `idmap config` lines in smb.conf not instructing Samba to get group membership information from `ldap.mydomain.com`?